# mod_rewrite rewriting base

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

i'm working on a website, where i'd like to use mod_rewrite for rewriting URLs like

> www.example.com/index.php?p=MYPAGE --> www.example.com/MYPAGE
>   www.example.com/index.php?p=user?u=MYUSER --> www.example.com/user/MYUSER
>   www.example.com/index.php?p=group?g=MYGROUP --> www.example.com/group/MYGROUP

I've added so far these rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ index.php?p=user&u=$1
```

but i'm facing a problem. if i visit www.example.com/single-page everything is fine. Then if i visit www.example.com/user/SMTHING, i'm not getting to what i want. I've tried using C and L flag, without any success.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: FYI: Rewrite questions are valid on both ServerFault and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No answer may look like mine, so here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?p=user&u=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^group/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?p=group&g=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm pretty sure it works (or very close to what you want).
Please tell me if it works...

By the way how about something nicer like:

```
RewriteRule ^(user|group)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?type=$1&val=$2 [QSA,L]
```

so in your GET you will have "type=user" or "type=group" and "val=the value". Kind of generalize stuff.

Comment: Of course it did! I'm the RewriteRules man! Check how I did my reputation LOL!

Answer (score 2):

You have three issues.  The first is that your conditions only apply to the first rule that follows them, so you'll still rewrite legitimate file requests.  Further, you need to use the [L]ast flag as well as re-order your rules like this. Putting it all together:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1                               [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1                               [L]

RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ index.php?p=user&u=$1       [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

will you try this 
it may be useful.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ index.php?p=user&u=$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1
```

The order of Rewrite rules is very important.

Comment: Swapping the 2 last lines caused more trouble. Now the website fails to load some css and js

Comment: The problem is that if you don't apply the [L]ast flag to a rule, all following rules are still evaluated, so a URL like `http://example.com/user/thisguy` will get rewritten by both rules to something like `http://example.com/index.php?p=index.php?p=user&u=thisguy`

Comment: You're right, i took a look at the mod_rewrite documentation to better understand [L] flag. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([^\/])([^\/]+)\/([^\.]+)$ index.php?p=$1$2&$1=$3
```